# Phone doesn't go to sleep?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible that if phone's screen turns off completely but phone does not go to sleep?

I have an app which do some things when device goes to sleep. I registered broadcast intent: Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF

On my device app works fine ( HTC Desire, cyanogenmod ). When screen turns off, my app is activated.

I tried app on another phone (HTC Wildfire S, offical gingerbread ), and here is the strange part. When screen goes off my app is not activated (sometimes it is, like 10%). So i connected it with my LOGCAT and i wanted to see if device actually goes to sleep when screen is turned off, and the thing is that when is connected with my PC, device ALWAYS goes to sleep and my app is activated.

On emulators from froyo to jelly bean app works perfect.  Is problem in my app?

Comment: If the device is rooted it could be the kernel used on it. Maybe the kernel is not going to sleep. Did you try other phones?

Comment: Well on rooted device app works fine. On offical ROM, its not working. I tested  on two real devices so far. I will do test today on two more ( when i get them in my hands )

Comment: Well it could still be the kernel, maybe the kernel that comes with the official ROM is not going to sleep.

Comment: When that devices screen goes off it doesnt happen anything. BUT if i press POWER button, my app is activated!

So maybe something..or some app is preventing phone to go to sleep? (is this possible ) ?

Comment: "when is connected with my PC, device ALWAYS goes to sleep and my app is activated"  Having the device connected to a computer over USB prevents the device from entering deep sleep, so there's a difference compared to when you don't have USB connected. Why that stops your app from being launched I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

From my testing of Screen Status broadcasts, I have learned that different manufacturers handle the screen off intents in different ways. Can't really depend on the phone.
You might want to use PowerManager to detect status of the device and take appropirate actions in onPause()

```
public static boolean isDeviceScreenOn(Context argContext) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) argContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    return pm.isScreenOn();
}
```